# Load script only in mobile not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, mobile

I found a script that works perfectly based on what I expect. It checks if there is a specific cookie and run certain condition. Until here, everything OK:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.cookie('bas_referral') == null ) {
      alert('There is no yet');
      console.log('setting cookie');
   var ref = document.referrer.toLowerCase();  
   // set cookie  
   var cookURL =  $.cookie('bas_referral', ref, { expires: 365 }); 
  } 
  else {alert('Now it has!')}; 
 });
```

Now, I want to load this same script ONLY in some resolution, but the code I've written it's not working. =\

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() &lt; 767) {

  if ($.cookie('bas_referral') == null ) {
      alert('There is no yet');
      console.log('setting cookie');
   var ref = document.referrer.toLowerCase();  
   // set cookie  
   var cookURL =  $.cookie('bas_referral', ref, { expires: 365 }); 
  } 
  else {alert('Now it has!')};
}

else {alert('Large screen');} 
 });
```

Does anyone know why and could help me? Since now, I thank you! =]

Comment: `&lt;` is html...not valid javascript. Check errors in browser console

Comment: charlieftl, I've been so distracted that I didn't realize this simple detail! I was formatting the code automatically to Blogger and I didn't change the &lt; It's working now! Thanks and God bless you! ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if ($(window).width() &lt; 767)`

is not a statement.
but `if ($(window).width() < 767)`
is